# How to remove all ".DS_Store" files from Google Cloud Storage with gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I've done a gsutil rsync before, which included a lot of ".DS_Store" files that I didn't want to sync.  Now I would like to get rid of them, but I can't seem to find a way of doing that.

The command I though would work is:

`gsutil rm gs://my-bucket/\*.DS_Store\*`

However, I'm getting an error stating "CommandException: No URLs matched:" when using this.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
gsutil -m rm -r gs://my-bucket/**/.DS_Store
```

Or with zsh

```
gsutil -m rm -r 'gs://my-bucket/**/.DS_Store'
```

Comment: When I use that command, I get an error stating `zsh: no matches found: gs://my-bucket/**/.DS_Store/*` (with my-bucket substituted of course).  I've checked and I definitely have .DS_Store files still in storage.

Comment: zsh is attempting up expand the wildcard before passing it to gsutil. Try putting the gs://my-bucket/**/.DS_Store/* argument in single quotes.

Comment: When I do that, it takes about a minute to run with only the cursor visible, before returning: `CommandException: No URLs matched: gs://my-bucket/**/.DS_Store/*`

Comment: I think you want `gs://my-bucket/**/.DS_Store` since it is a file, not a folder.

Comment: Mateus Ribeiro you need to install gsutil and run it from the shell.